# When printing to Excel in SQL Service Reporting Services a rendering error is shown

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I am a report that on page 1 shows 3 charts and then on all subsequent pages shows a Tablix output of column / row data. I was making edits to it earlier today and adding two new columns to the query that generates the Tablix output and ever since when I attempt to print to Excel I receive the following:

```
Reporting Services Error

An error occurred during rendering of the report. (rrRenderingError)
An error occurred during rendering of the report.
Excel Rendering Extension : Argument is not valid. 

SQL Server Reporting Services
```

I am unclear if this is due to my modifications of the Dataset and corresponding Tablix or if it is due to the amount of data being put into the Tablix as one of my columns is a notes column that at times can be lengthy.

I own and have full access to the SSRS server so can reboot / restart services / etc.

Any help in resolving is much appreciated?

Thanks!

Comment: According to this Microsofts documentation on SSRS, the maximum column width is 255 characters. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017
There are other limitations also, which you may be running into.

Comment: OK so simple test would be to remove the notes column. So column deleted and print to Excel starts functioning again. However this used to work so i guess the notes being added to records are now growing in size and causing this issue. Thanks this at least gets me moving in the right direction.

Comment: Although the maximum **displayable** column width is 255 characters, the **maximum number of characters in one cell is 32,767.** If this is exceeded, the renderer displays an error message. I would check your maximum data length in the column with the notes field, and advise the business users about the max length limit for one cell, and where it is exceeded in the data.

Comment: Done! Thank you!